# override/edit the chrome cookies file when chrome is running

Tags: c#, windows, file, google-chrome, cookies

I am building a c# program to insert a new cookies into chrome browser with SQLITE connection. 
The logic and connection are almost done and they are working well. 
The only problem left is it cannot edit or override the cookies file when chrome is running. Is it possible to replace/edit the cookies file when chrome is running? Please give me some advice. Thanks.

current: If i use sqlite connect, the cookies data can be read but cannot insert/update record. "disk I/O error" is prompted.

If I use replace cookies file, the file is used by chrome.

Comment: No because the file is in use by Chrome.

Comment: Any alternative to do so?

Comment: Create a chrome plugin?

Comment: some dll is included in my application which used for calculation. Using dll in chrome extension will be banned in the future.

Comment: Then you better write your calculations in Javasdcript.

Comment: unlikely, the calculation involves the USB card reader which should be in a local environment. I am not sure I am correct or not.